# how to indicate permission when reusing a figure from a published study

Tags: publications, writing, copyright, publishers

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202362/using-a-simple-figure-in-a-published-paper-in-a-grant-proposal/202367#202367) regarding the inclusion of a figure in my grant proposal.

I followed the necessary steps and obtained permission, which was granted free of charge. I received an email with the subject line 'Thank you for your order with RightsLink / John Wiley and Sons.' However, I am unsure whether this confirms that I have obtained permission.

Assuming that I do have permission, what do I do with it? Should I include a statement in the figure caption indicating that permission was obtained (include the order number)?

I have observed instances in which figures from one study were reused in another study, but I have never encountered cases where permission for such reuse was explicitly discussed in their captions.

The linked [post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120916/permissions-to-reproduce-an-image-while-writing-review-papers) (suggested duplicates) is not an answer for how to indicate permission, although it provides an example in which permission is noted. In particular, it states that one way to indicate that permission is obtained is to say:

***Reproduced with permission from [ref]***

However, citing the paper for permission is not necessarily accurate when the permission does not belong to the published paper itself.

Also, is proof of permission (e.g., License Number) not needed? Do you only have to provide proof when someone asks for it?

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn't make sense. The first sentence says you obtained permission. The last doubts the truth of that. Which is it?

Comment: @Buffy This is because I did not know what proof of permission looks like. I purchased permission for $0 from a website and received the receipt, but I was not sure whether the receipt was considered proof of permission.

Later, I found a link in the receipt in which they state:

'This Agreement between ("You") and John Wiley and Sons ("John Wiley and Sons") consists of your license details and the terms and conditions provided by John Wiley and Sons and Copyright Clearance Center.'

So, I now believe that I have proper permission. The link also contains a License Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way is to include, at the end of the citation of the original, "Used with permission" or "Included with permission". If the citation itself doesn't make clear who the rights holder is, then "Used with permission of John Wiley & Sons".